# How programmatically fill field "display as" in outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook

When creating  `taskitem` or `appointmentitem` exist field "To". I can search to this field only into **FistName** but need **LastName**.

If I change field "display as" on contact than I can search into lastName. How change field "display as" programmatically?

I add recipient:

```
 task.Assign();
 task.Recipients.Add("some@email.com");
```

Comment: How was the task recipient added? Was that a one-off SMTP address or a GAL user?

Comment: one-off SMTP address!I need search no-programmaticaly!

Comment: What is your code that adds the recipient?

Answer (score 0):

You possibly want `ContactItem.Email1DisplayName`

You can read more about [Email1DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._contactitem.email1displayname.aspx)

(And maybe [Email2DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._contactitem.email2displayname.aspx) and [Email3DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._contactitem.email3displayname.aspx))